# mspaint problem "this is not a valid bitmap file"

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-paint

I have Vista Business on my laptop. I download JPG pictures from my Nikkon camera. I open them with mspaint and resize them. Then save them back as jpg (using the jpg option). When I try to open the saved file, I get "**Paint cannot read this file. This is not a valid bitmap file**". When I preview it with windows photo gallery, I can see the picture. Any ideas?

Comment: No idea on your issues but you really shouldn't resize images with Paint. Nearest neighbor resampling is ugly, to say the least. You can easily manage pictures and change their size with Windows Live Photo Gallery, though.

Comment: Use Paint.NET. It's free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How are you saving them as .jpg ? Did you select JPEG in the file format options? (I believe paint defaults to .bmp, so you may have a .bmp save with a .jpg extension).

However, as people have already said in the comments, Paint is not a great program for any serious image editing tasks. A good free alternative is [Paint.NET](http://getpaint.net), it has most of Paint's ease of use, with a much larger feature set.

Comment: I selected jpeg option

Comment: As it happens, even if you give a bmp a jpg extension it still opens fine in Paint.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue today and as far as I can tell it has to do with the resolution of the image. From my testing today, it seems that any image above 1200*1200dpi won't open in Paint, even if it is a BMP file or even if it is only 4MB in size It seems to be purely resolution related.
See this thread:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/paint-wont-open-valid-file-types-over-1200x1200/176a85c8-ac6a-4e1a-a6e2-6b7ce7190ea7

Until Microsoft fix it, I would suggest using Paint.net or GIMP. They're both completely free (and ad free) and easy to use with some more advanced features too if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

It's a size issue. The Fujifilm GFX 100 S produces TIF that will neither open in Paint nor in Portrait Pro.

Solution: Crop the image slightly in Photoshop or Corel. Then it will behave normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the file is good anyways, you can install Image Magick and run in cmd:

```
identify imagename
```

replace imagename by the name of the actual file if there's and error thaty comand will clearly tell you.